# How to assign value from data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have two data frames as follows:

A.
[image: Country1 Country2 Country3]

B. [image]

And I want to assign a specific value based on country and year. The result should be

C. [image]

Anyone know how to do automatically? Because table A has over 2,000 rows and 30 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to reshape the second data into 'long' format and then do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Country, names_to = 'Year', values_to = 'Value') %>%
    left_join(df1, .)
#   Country Year  Value
#1 Country1 1990 value1
#2 Country2 1991 value5
#3 Country3 1991 value6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Country = c("Country1", "Country2", "Country3"
), Year = c("1990", "1991", "1991")), row.names = c(NA, -3L),
class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Country = c("Country1", "Country2", "Country3"
), `1990` = c("value1", "value2", "value3"), `1991` = c("value4", 
"value5", "value6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```